# c# - DateTime conversion terminates foreach loop

Tags: c#, datetime, foreach

I am taking a vehicle ID and two dates from a form and a vehicle ID and daily rental rate from a table to calculate and display the cost of a booking.

I convert the `datetime`s from the form to a string and then try and convert them to `datetime`s.  This conversion terminates the foreach loop.  I have removed the conversion and everything else works.

Here is my code with the offending conversions commented out.

```
            DataTable dt = database1DataSet.Tables["Fleet"];
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            string currentViD = dr["VehicleID"].ToString();
            string tableViD = vehicleIDTextBox.Text;
            string tableRate = dr["VehicleStdRate/day"].ToString();
            int numericRate = Convert.ToInt16(tableRate);
            int cost;
            string displayCost;
            TimeSpan x = dayInDateTimePicker - dayOutDateTimePicker;
            string y = dayOutDateTimePicker.ToString();
            string z = dayInDateTimePicker.ToString();
            //DateTime DayOut = Convert.ToDateTime(y);
            //DateTime DayIn = Convert.ToDateTime(z);
            int duration = 10; //placeholder
            if (currentViD.Equals(tableViD) == true)
            {
                cost = numericRate * duration;
                displayCost = cost.ToString();
                bookingCostTextBox.Text = displayCost;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please instead of all unrelated code keep `string y= "some value you see while debugging";` and remove all other content from `foreach` loop.

Comment: Is there an error?  If so, what does the message state?  Also, have you stepped through the code?  If so, what were the values of `y` and `z`?

Comment: Is that break intentional? If you take the if then your code exits the loop

Comment: I'm just curious, why would you want to do this? (or do you just want to know why it breaks the foreach)

Comment: I'm assuming you're getting an exception. What are the contents of `y` and `z` immediately before you attempt to convert them?

Comment: No exception. y and z are '01/03/2013 00:00:00' and '07/03/2013 00:00:00' and the break is intentionalto exit the loop. The foreach and the if complete without the conversions and display what I intend.

Comment: you should really make your variable names `meaningful`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5dy31w8.aspx)**.

> *Returns a string that represents the current DateTimePicker control.*

Use `dayOutDateTimePicker.Value.ToString()` instead.